# Nib not overlayed over camera view

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, camera, xib

I'm working on a project that has a custom camera control view.  I took a look at apple's docs and tried to write my code around the documentation.  Right now the nib doesn't load but the camera is appearing.

Here's the code I got:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cameraView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.overlayView.frame = imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
    imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
    self.overlayView = nil;
    self.imagePickerController = imagePickerController;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I did make sure that I linked my class with the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and the `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

Also, I am using iOS 7 so if that's a compatibility problem then please let me know.  None of the code prompted with a warning saying my code is depreciated and also the app doesn't crash.  It shows images from my camera but just not the nib.

**EDIT**
I know I should be checking if the device has a camera but right now I just want to make sure I can get the camera to work first.  Probably not my best choice but unfortunately that's just how my mind works and I'll go crazy if I don't get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to link my view with my class.  My mistake.